# NoMethodError in Reservations#new con un form_for en Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Estoy haciendo un sistema de arriendo de cabañas en RoR y me surge este error en la vista `new` de `Reservations` (reservas), el cual da cuando trato de crear un formulario en la vista. Si muestro el objeto vacío que pasa el controlador no me lanza error, por lo cual ambas rutas que especifico mas abajo llegan a la vista y pasan por el controlador.

> NoMethodError in Reservations#new
>
> undefined method `reservations_path' for #<#
>   :0x007f73f8791260>
>   Did you mean?  resolve_asset_path

La vista *resvervations/new.html.erb* es esta:

```
<%= render  'formulario' %>
```

La cual llama al formulario *reservations/_formulario.html.erb*:

```
<%= form_for(@reservation, :html => { :role => "form" }) do |f| %>
  <p>
  <%=f.label :tipo  %>
  <%=f.date_field :tipo %>
  </p>
  <p>
  <%=f.label :description %>
  <%=f.date_field :description %>
  </p>
  <%=f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

El controlador *reservations_controller.rb* tiene esto:

```
class ReservationsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @reservation = Reservation.new
  end
```

Mi *routes.rb* es el siguente:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  root 'cabins#index'

  resources :customers, :cabins do
    resource :reservations
  end

  get 'cabins/:id/index', to: 'reservations#index'
  get ':id/new', to: 'reservations#new', as: 'new_reservation'
end
```

Hice dos rutas que llevan a la vista `new`, ambas son redirigidas desde la vista *cabins/index*, la cual le pasa `@cabin`.

La relación  de los modelos es esta:

```
class Customer < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :reservations, :dependent => :delete_all
  has_many :cabins , through: :reservations
end

class Reservation < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :customer
  belongs_to :cabin
  has_one :payment
end

class Cabin < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :reservations, :dependent => :delete_all
  has_many :customers , through:  :reservations, :dependent => :delete_all
  has_many :bicycles, :dependent => :delete_all
  has_many :services, :dependent => :delete_all
end
```

Muchas Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dado que tienes una ruta personalizada (i.e. `get ':id/new', to: 'reservations#new', as: 'new_reservation'`) tienes que especificar la url en el *helper* `form_for`:

```
<%= form_for(@reservation, url: new_reservation_path, html: { role: "form" }) do |f| %>
```